# Excel data checking

Tags: excel, date, userform, worksheet, vba

## Excel data checking

I have an Excel UserForm which contains the following fields; `date`, `name` and `work`.

In the event that the worksheet contains the same date and name pairing, I want data transfer from the Userform blocked.

## Example

A worksheet has one entry:

- Column `A` has the date `1/1/2017`
- Column `B` has the name `john`

For the worksheet above, the following rules apply:

1. Information can be passed from the UserForm for `3/1/2017` and `john`.
2. Information can be passed from the UserForm for `1/1/2017` and `jane`.
3. Information cannot be passed from the UserForm for `1/1/2017` and `john`.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim k As Long
Dim matched As Boolean
matched = False

' Loop over all used rows
For k = 1 to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ' Check if concatenated string of date & name is unique
    ' e.g. '01/01/17john'
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(k, "A").Text & ActiveSheet.Cells(k, "B").Text = _
       myUserForm.DateField.Text & myUserForm.NameField.Text Then

        MsgBox "This Name / Date combination is not unique, pick again"

        matched = True

        Exit For

    End If

Next k

If matched = False Then

    ' Name/Date combination is unique, send data to sub or whatever... 

End If
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir

Comment: @Yogesh Please mark the answer as accepted if this did what you want :) (click the white/green tick mark at the top-left of this question)