# Excel Data checking to flag up duplicates

Tags: excel

I am trying to use code submitted by @Wolfie [Excel Data Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959118/excel-data-checking/44719354#44719354) to flag up duplicate entries where the date and specific code match. On my database, the date is in column B, The unique Code is in Column L, and is comprised of 2 letters and 2 numbers (i.e. AA22)

The database has Columns A to Q, and there is no limit to the number of rows it may have.

I have tried to amend your code to the following -

```
Dim q As Long
Dim matched As Boolean
matched = False

' Loop over all used rows
For q = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ' Check if concatenated string of date & name is unique
    ' e.g. '01/01/17john'
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(q, "B").Text & ActiveSheet.Cells(q, "L").Text = _
       myUserForm.DateField.Text & myUserForm.NameField.Text Then

        MsgBox "This Duty / Date combination has already been entered, please check for previous entry"

        matched = True

        Exit For

    End If

Next q

If matched = False Then

    ' Name/Date combination is unique, send data to sub or whatever...

End If
```

I don't think my database has been set up as a userform, so perhaps that might be what is causing the problem?

If someone can point out what it is I am missing, I would be very grateful.

If someone is feeling extremely generous, there is one extra tweak that would be fantastic for me. I have a column (K) that allows only 3 options HGW; RDW & O/T. If HGW or RDW are selected, then the duplication flag must show. However if the O/T is selected then it doesn't flag up as a duplicate.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match whether data entered by a user is a duplicate, that can be done without VBA. The code above seems to check this when data is entered via a userform.

If you don't enter data with a userform, you could just as well use a helper column with a formula along the lines of

```
=if(isnumber(match(B2&L2,Index($B$1:$B1&$L$1:L1,0),0)),"duplicate","")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use a worksheet_change event with code similar to the above.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim q As Long
Dim matched As Boolean
matched = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L:L")) Is Nothing Then

' Loop over all used rows
For q = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count -1

    ' Check if concatenated string of date & name is unique
    ' e.g. '01/01/17john'
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(q, "B").Value & ActiveSheet.Cells(q, "L").Value = _
       Target.Offset(0, -10).Value & Target.Value Then

        MsgBox "This Duty / Date combination has already been entered, please check for previous entry"

        matched = True

        Exit For

    End If

Next q
End If

If matched = False Then

    ' Name/Date combination is unique, send data to sub or whatever...

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @teylyn for trying to come up with a working possibility. I have added the VBA code to the database, but for some reason it is showing the message that the the information is duplicated, but this is happening on every entry, not just when a duplicate is found! I would upload the database for you to see, except I have no idea how it is done!!

Comment: You may have to adjust the formula to apply to the correct columns and rows. If the formula starts in row 5, you can't use `match(B2&L2`, of course, and if the date and name are not in B and L, then you need to adjust that, too. The formula works, as you can see in my screenshot. So, now just make sure to apply it to your data correctly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @teylyn, I hadn't tried the formula version, as I didn't want an extra column into the database (it is already very wide!). If you could get the formula to provide a splash screen instead when a duplicate is found, then I could create the column, and then hide it so it works in the background. I had tried using the vba script, which was where I encountered the problem of it highlighting every entry as a duplicate! I need the code to check from row 3 onwards, with no limit of rows to check, eventually, as new enties will be added to the bottom of the list.

Comment: A formula can't trigger a message box. The code I posted runs on the row where the data is entered, so that triggers the message. I adjusted the code to not use the current row `For q = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1`

Comment: Hi @teylyn, I have been tinkering with the database to try and get it to work. Your vba code works, but in the wrong direction! Instead of showing duplicate message when I have added a date in column B and a duty number (AA21) in column L, nothing happens. Only when I delete the duty number in column L does the message appear! The duplicate message doesn't appear when I delete the date though.

Comment: If you only ever add new data at the bottom the code will work. I just edited the code you provided to work outside of a Userform. It's not the best code and it is not very robust. The use of ActiveRange is not the best way to do this, because the ActiveRange will not shrink when values are deleted, and then it will compare too many rows, hence the false posistives. But as far as I'm concerned, looping through all the rows is not the best way to do this either.

Comment: The point of my answer was to run the code outside of a userform, not to totally re-write a procedure that is off to begin with. You should close this question by accepting the answer, then start a new question to fix what's wrong with the architecture of that code.

Comment: In any case, you need to understand the code, so you can change it. After all, you're posting on a site for "professional and enthusiast programmers", so some knowledge about programming is actually expected of you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @teylyn, much appreciated. I will go back to the drawing board & try to work out a better code for what I want to do.